# How to change the inserted value during the insertion?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl, c++14

I would like to insert the values from vector `b` to vector `a`, and multiply the values by -1 during the insertion. Currently I simply insert the elements, and multiply them by -1 afterwards:

```
a.insert(std::end(a), std::begin(b), std::end(b));
// ...
```

How is it possible to get the negative values already during the insertion, withoud modifying the original `b` vector?

What I would like to achieve:

```
old a = {2,3,4}
b = {3,4,5}

a = {2,3,4,-3,-4,-5}
```

Comment: What if you just have a temp array with all values of b multiplied by -1, then dispose of it?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use [`std::transform`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) like this:

```
#include <algorithm>

std::transform(std::cbegin(b), std::cend(b), std::back_inserter(a), std::negate<>());
```

Comment: Also `a.reserve(a.size() + b.size())` is a good idea! Anyways, nice sln using STD.